# Overriding table reference in model.builder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, model

My ultimate objective is to reference a table and delete its contents.

there is  a code block in my 'OnModelCreating' of dbContext :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SpecialOfferVersion>()
                .HasMany(x => x.Airports)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(x =>
                {
                    x.ToTable("SpecialOfferVersionAirport");
                    x.MapLeftKey("SpecialOfferVersionId");
                    x.MapRightKey("AirportCode");
                });
```

I want to reference Table 'SpecialOfferVersionAirport',How can I do that?

I tried

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SpecialOfferVersionAirport>().ToTable("SpecialOfferVersionAirport");
```

but errors :

*Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
(6637,6) : error 0019: The EntitySet 'SpecialOfferVersionAirport1' with schema 'dbo' and table 'SpecialOfferVersionAirport' was already defined. Each EntitySet must refer to a unique schema and table.*

Comment: I think SpecialOfferVersionAirport table was already created automatically as a junction table for the many-to-many relationship

Comment: but how can i reference it,we do normally do this thru db context rt ?

Comment: it's hard to reference it. why do you want to do so?

Comment: as my queston states "My ultimate objective is to reference a table and delete its contents" .

Comment: you can manually remove associated entities to a table for example: specialOffer.Airports.Remove(airport); to clear all associated use: specialOffer.Airports.Clear();